# Agregar un nuevo JSON un arreglo en Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Estoy usando mongo para almacenar los permisos de un usuario en nodo se llama `permissions` y dentro de este hay nodos que tienen el nombre de cada una de las secciones de mi app. Dentro de cada uno de ellos, existe un conjunto de valores para identificar si el usuario puede hacer algo o no dentro de la aplicación

Les muestro como viene el nodo de `permissions`

```
permissions: {
    "dashboard": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
    "meals": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
    "ingredients": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
    "users": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
}
```

Ahora, quiero agregar una nueva sección (A nivel de users, por ejemplo) con unos valores por defecto, esta es la query que estoy usando

```
db.getCollection('users').updateOne({ nick_name: 'a.siurob' }, 
{ 
    $push: { 
        'permissions': {
            'account_control': {
                'update': true,
                'read': true,
                'create': true,
                'delete': true
            }
        } 
    } 
});
```

Esto me regresa un error

```
The field 'permissions' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('618d6aeb93b594490ea6c2eb')}
```

¿Qué está pasando con mi query? ¿Qué está mal?

Comment: Sería útil ver el modelo

Comment: Ya lo resolví Luis, pero tu comentario me ayudó a entender otra cosa que estaba haciendo mal, llevaba 1 hora buscando el error, y estaba en el modelo

Comment: Tenía sentido que viniera por ese lado, me alegra mucho que resolvieras, a las órdenes.

Comment: Alberto, yo sugeriría otra estrategia para almacenar los permisos, sobre todo si en cada documento se repite siempre las mismas claves: *create, read, update, delete*. Saludos

Comment: En cuanto a tu `query`, sólo puedes usar `$push` sobre campos de tipo `Array` y `permissions` no lo es. Saludos